# amsmath theorem name as argument

Tags: amsmath, theorems

How can I have an amsmath Theorem environment where the name of the environment is passed as an argument?

e.g.

```
\begin{note}[Name of the Theorem]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
    magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\end{note}
\begin{note}[A different name]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
    magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\end{note}
```

resulting in this:[image]

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Added a second example for clarity

Answer (score 0):

See the tutorial about the Pythagorean theorem on [this page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/theorems_and_proofs).

You can add a theorem title using brackets:

```
\begin{theorem}[Pythagorean theorem]
```

EDIT: here is an exemple, but I am not sure that is what you are looking for.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theoremApple}{Apple}
\newtheorem{theoremBanana}{Banana}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Apple]
The apple is red.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}[Banana]
The banana is yellow.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theoremApple}
The apple is red.
\end{theoremApple}
\begin{theoremBanana}
The banana is yellow.
\end{theoremBanana}
\begin{theoremApple}
Actually, the apple is green.
\end{theoremApple}

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

Comment: That I know, but I want to replace the "Theorem" with the name given in the argument.